# WordPress Comment functions

Tags: functions

As we know we can usually make changes to "the content" by calling the_content(). is there any equivalent function available for comments? or any such way do you know?

Answer (score 1):

I do hope I understand what you're asking, as you're not giving much information. From what I specifically to customize the output of your comments.

Well, there partially is. The [wp_list_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) accepts a *callback* argument among several others. This *callback* allows you to run a custom function; in your case, a custom function to manipulate the comments' markup/output.

So, let's get started. Assuming your HTML structure looks somewhat like this:

```
<ul class="comments">
   <?php $args = array(
        'type'          => 'comment',
        'callback'        => custom_comments
   );
   wp_list_comments($args); ?>
</ul>
```

Then, you would create a function called *custom_comments*, that would look something like this:
function custom_comments($args, $comment, $depth) {
    // your code..
    // example from DigWP: http://pastie.org/2986583
}

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

This [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference#Comment.2C_Ping.2C_and_Trackback_Functions) lists many functions for comments.

Comment: Thanks,I checked that.But I didn't found what I'm searching for.